# Why do we fast on Taanis Esther in particular?

Tags: minhag, purim, fast-days, army-military-war

I am aware that [according to the Avudraham, the fast commemorates the war in the Purim story](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8659/9682).

**According to this answer,** why is Taanis Esther unique that we fast in memory of the war, when there are so many wars in our history that we do not fast over?

Comment: If I read the Megillah correctly, the fast of Esther occurred almost immediately after Mordechai showed Esther the document that declared Haman's plans to destroy the Jews almost a year later. The fast extended into Pesach. Isn't that what our current fast is commemorating? If not, what became of the focus / purpose of the fast?

Comment: @DanF Again, for *why* we fast, see the linked answer. I'm asking specifically on this particular reason cited there.

Comment: @Efraim Again. I am asking based off of an answer to that question. I really didn't think this was that complicated.

Comment: The most comprehensive analysis of Ta'anis Esther was done by Mitchell First. He published a paper which can be found here (which can be read for free but is pay-blocked to download): https://www.jstor.org/stable/40982835?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents. The paper has been summarized very well by the author himself here: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2011/03/origin-of-taanit-esther.html .    And is available to buy as part of a book he published: https://www.amazon.com/Esther-Unmasked-Solving-Mysteries-Holidays/dp/0692375422

Comment: @mevaqesh That better?

Comment: @Ephraim I'm not sure I would call his weird theory (convincing people not to fast on Friday or Shabbos) which he admits has no real reasoning behind it, the most comprehensive analysis.

Comment: DonielF consider which other war a holiday was instituted in commemoration of and then we can wonder why this war got a fast too. And when chanuka comes to mind, let's consider the different ways the holidays were instituted and wonder again if there is anything really unprecedented with this fast.

Comment: @user6591 Chanukah was instituted because of the menorah. The war continued on for many years after the Chag was instituted.

Comment: @DonielF whether it is from the menorah or the war seems to be a machlokes. And if anything the opinion you quote just means purim is the only holiday instituted due to a threat and war so my point stands.

Comment: @user6591 Either way, why do we have a *fast* to celebrate the war? We never *fast* in commemoration of a war.

Comment: We also never have a holiday in commemoration of a war.

Comment: @user6591 An excellent question. Why don't you ask it? I don't see how it applies here. Maybe we shouldn't fast, and instead we should have a two-day Purim.

Comment: Or maybe we shouldn't have a day to party and we should fast for two. I'm not sure what is so hard to get about my point. Purim is unprecedented. Everything surrounding it is unprecedented. Pointing to one particular aspect and asking 'why' seems like an approach I wouldn't take. That's all. I'm not negating your question, just pointing out that you can point to any aspect of the commemoration abs ask why did they institute that?

Answer (score -1):

Rav Jachter [explains](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/taanitesther.htm), "The Amoraim (according to Rabbeinu Tam) or the Geonim (according to Rashi) instituted Taanit Esther as a fast just like all other fasts." There have certainly been many fast-worthy wars we have endured throughout our history, but we would need Chazal to institute one.

(See Rav Ari Enkin's alternative [answers](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/taanitesther.htm) as to why we fast which would avoid the question altogether.)

Comment: I'm asking specifically according to the answer that it's to commemorate the war. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @DonielF If you want to ask according to only one opinion make sure to edit your question to reflect this. (It appears that that opinion is likely wrong, so it will preclude good answer, but that is your problem). It is unfair to downvote an answer for quoting sources you disagree with, unless you clarify that only sources sharing your preconception are acceptable.